# WireShark messages

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012, wireshark

I Wrote an application in vs2012 in python and I want to see the messages that are being sent and recieved to the application.
When I open wireshark I see a lot of messages go through.
Is there a way to focus wireshark on only my application?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by messages? Network IO, sockets etc.?

Comment: I think it's not possible to listen to a specific application afaik. But you might listen for TCP-Messages (Note: Maybe scapy might be an alternative, it's like wireshark for python) [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/88444/capture-traffic-for-specific-application) are some suggestions for alternatives

Answer (score 1):

If you know the port number used by the application you can filter by that port by putting `tcp.port == 1234` in the filter toolbar.